# Is there Firefox preference for controlling JavaScript redirect?

Tags: firefox, security, website, redirection

There is a user preference to disallow a [sneaky redirect](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66355) and display a warning instead:
[image]

However, extent of this preference seems to be limited to

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.dollarade.com/noscript.php">
```

kind of sneaky redirects and the malicious web-page can easily circumvent this restriction by using

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">if (!hasloaded) { window.location = 'http://www.dollarade.com/adblock.php'; }</script>
```

So, the question is: is there an advanced setting (about:config may be?) to take control back over JavaScript-driven sneaky redirects?

<sub>If anyone is curious for more: [here](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6853) is user's complaint and sample page from the wild. Note how Firefox omits the history entry due sneaky redirect, making studying an offending page really unconvenient.</sub>

Comment: How about noScript, I belive it has that kind of feature.

Answer (score 2):

You won't necessarily be able to modify how Firefox handles this specific function by using built-in controls, but you can certainly download an add-on such as [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) which will restrict Javascript's ability to redirect you (and just about everything else Javascript may try to do).

Comment: With the plugin NoScript you are able to stop/block any script on a web page one by one